# How to get Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010-express

I am working on a Source Mod, and it requires that I use Microsoft Visual C++ Express, and the compiler that goes with it. However, all of the links that Google brings up just redirect me to the newer Visual Studio Community.

Does anyone know where I can still install Visual C++ Express 2010 on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*VS 2010 Express Edition* is no longer available from Microsoft downloads.

You can still find [VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673), [VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48131), and there is a [VS 2015 Express for Windows Desktop](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) but generally the *VS 2013 Community* or *VS 2015 Community* editions are a much better experience and have better support for tools and features that were only in the professional products previously which is why searches are pointing you to it.